# How should users share long log files?

Tags: discussion, best-practice

For underdeveloped troubleshooting questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42336/my-computer-has-begun-to-restart-after-i-updated-to-ubuntu-11-04) I want to look at whole log files such as `/var/log/syslog.1` or `/var/log/kern.log.1`, which can be several thousands of lines long.

How should users share this kind of information on Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: This makes me wonder how we could help users remove or avoid posting sensitive information that could be contained in a log file. (For example, what if the user didn't realize that a program had saved their current latitude & longitude into the log?) I'm always nervous about that sort of thing happening to me.

Comment: @Firefeather This is an important issue. Perhaps we can learn from similar discussions about the collection of sensitive data in Apport.

Comment: you mention a very good point. I haven't come across a discussion about sensitive data in Apport bug reporting, but I'm familiar with the warning in the Apport GUI. Do you, by chance, have a link to the discussion (and its possible resolution)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest using http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: What is a reasonable upper limit in file size for this utility? My web browser starts to crawl when I copy and paste twenty thousand lines of logs into a text field.

Comment: 25k lines were no problem here, but copying from gedit failed, so I opened it in the browser and copied it from there.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to htorque's suggestion of [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com), I found there is a command line app that can be used to make it easier:

[`pastebinit`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit)[image: Install pastebinit]

It's quite relevant considering *ændrük's* comment about problems pasting very large log into the browser.

An example:

`df -h | pastebinit -b http://paste.ubuntu.com`

---

The only question I have about *paste.ubuntu.com* is that there is no information about the expiry of the url and no explicit option to make it longer, such as [dpaste](http://dpaste.com/).

Answer (score 9):

It is generally a bad idea to post enormous log files. Who is going to read an enormous wall of text? It's a disincentive to answering.

Generally, try to post *the most relevant section* of the log file, then link to the full file elsewhere.

Give it a shot, at least.. since the full file is linked, it's the best of both worlds.

Comment: I think a common problem is that for many users finding what's relevant in a wall of (obscure) text is the hard part. Hence wanting to paste up the whole shebang. There's always Ctrl+F to do a quick search once it's been posted to, say, http://paste.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Speaking as an answerer, it takes me a lot more energy to deal with askers who won't post full logs (Post all the lines containing `sda`. No, not the first five lines, all of them. No, actually I need to see `/md`. Ok, I see the first symptom, now I need everything before this line. No, that line) than to locate what's wrong in a long log (if I have a chance of knowing the answer). Posting partial logs is like posting partial error messages. Don't do it.

Comment: @gilles that's incompatible with our engine; you want 50,000 character log files in every post? Or, worse, just "FIX MY PROBLEM (link to log file)?" No thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff's point is valid when you know what is the relevant part of the log - but when you don't, it's best to resort to Ubuntu Pastebin to "paste up the whole shebang" as boehj puts it.