# A request for all Ask Ubuntu users

Tags: discussion, formatting

About a week ago the Indian Government has Blocked(read Banned) a few sites,one of them is `pastebin.com`. I have seen a few people linking their errors to pastebin so I sincerely request them to choose some other site

The Alternatives are

- https://gist.github.com/
- http://paste.ubuntu.com
- http://pastie.org/
- http://codepad.org/
- http://www.pasteall.org/
- http://0bin.net/
- http://ideone.com/
- https://pastee.org/
- http://tinypaste.com/
- http://www.safebin.net/

Some more alternatives [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/pastebin/)

Comment: I am also from india ,but still I can access pastebin ,is it unblocked?

Comment: nope depends on your isp . all major isps like mtnl, reliance, have blocked it. what isp ur using?

Comment: Bsnl :bharath sanchar nigam limited

Comment: here is one such article http://techie-buzz.com/india-telecom/private-indian-isp-blocks-the-pirate-bay-vimeo-pastebinno-reason-given.html

Comment: & thanks to you i got a workaround (see the last two lines of that article). edit - the workaround works for pastebin but not for piratebay :(

Comment: confirming BSNL works for pastebin

Comment: it might soon be blocked. initially mtnl didnt block those sites only reliance had done that but soon mtnl followed and now most probably bsnl will do that too. but nothing to worry theres a workaround for everything (Even cheating the SE server ;D)

Comment: Why is India censoring pastebin???

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Many say that theres a indian film going to be realeased so to prevent piracy......... also pastebin is a well known hub for piracy links

Comment: Confirming BSNL works. To unblock this, change your dns servers to the ones by google. And about the movie @GeorgeEdison Its the new tamil movie by Danush named "3". Their trying to "stop" piracy. You can distribute torrents via pastebin.

Comment: I never used the sites you have given. But may be I will visit them in future. Well i use a mobile modem which uses Tata DoCoMo sim for my internet(2G)

Comment: pastebin works for me i have MTNL!

Comment: @utkarsh this is about last year

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pastebin is no longer banned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pastebin that we encourage is the official Ubuntu Pastebin, [`paste.ubuntu.com`](http://paste.ubuntu.com)

Here's to hoping that it gets unblocked soon!

Comment: yeah hope so... they even blockd vimeo and dailymotion ... wat retards!!

Comment: this is the first time I hear of paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I agree, this is the official paste bin that should be used by Ask Ubuntu, or at least encouraged for users to use.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: Well, it does have a few rendering quirks though, so I usually use [this](http://dpaste.com).

Comment: Linked information in your question will break sooner or later, rendering the question (and our answers) useless for others. I think you shouldn't use external sites like pastehumptydumpty.com at all. If the text is related to your question, put it in your question. This is the only way to keep the question and its context valuable for future reference.

Comment: @jippie So you really want users to paste their 300 line log file in the question? Meh.

Comment: @jrg so you rather want questions/answers/efforts to be rendered worthless once documents on pastebin (or the like) expire, rather than editing back those logs in the question? I for one will not be doing any effort on work that breaks over time because of external dependencies.

Comment: @jippie If you really want to discourage usage of 'external dependencies', then I suggest you open up another meta question about [this topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1373/how-should-users-share-long-log-files).

Comment: @jrg I understand the issue of long log files, and I think it is important that the correct logging is contained *in* the question itself. I understand not everybody is able/tries to filter the logging to a reasonable minimum. Maybe paste.stackexchange.com would be a good alternative as probably more SE sites will face similar issues. At least the content will be in the stackexchange network, if something breaks stackexchange should be able to fix it.

Comment: @jippie The topic has been discussed before (although in this context it's jsFiddle, not pastebin-type stuff). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stack-overflow. So I think the answer is "it's Ok" to use these things. If you don't agree, open a meta post. Comments are **not** the place for this.

Comment: OK, fair enough.